# Evaluating similar complex and covering indexes in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing, sql-server-2014

Let's say we have a table `MyTable` with columns `A`-`F`.

There are different queries selecting from the table. After using the excellent sp_BlitzIndex from Brent Ozar we find out that there are several missing indexes suggested. A lot of the indexes are similar and some of the same columns are recommended either in the ON clause or the INCLUDE clause.

For example we have the following recommended indexes:

```
create index index01 on MyTable (B) include (A, C, D)
create index index02 on MyTable (C, B) include (A, D)
create index index02 on MyTable (B, D) include (C)
```

Instead of just blindly create all of these indexes... Is it possible to say something general about cases like this and combine two or more of these indexes?

Comment: How much time would these indexes save? What's the cost benefit? Also, you need to consider how often the table is written to. If it's a read-only table then more indexes won't hurt but if you're writing to it regularly then the more indexes you have the slower your inserts (and updates/deletes) will be. Take a look st sp_BlitzIndex, see how it evaluates these indexes.

Comment: That's what the "Database Tuning Advisor" does. It compares the execution plans,  benefits and storage used by possible index combinations and proposes to create those that offer the greatest benefit

Comment: @rich-benner, we use sp_BlitzIndex all the time - great tool - but even BlitzIndex kan suggest to add indexes like

create index someindex on MyTable (A) include (B,C)
create index someindex on MyTable (A) include (D)

Those two indexes can easily be combined into 

create index someindex on MyTable (A) include (B,C, D)

I was wondering if it was possible to say something generel about the situation explained in the post